# Using camel as a directory watcher

Tags: apache-camel

Since a week I am dealing with the apache camel framework. I wanted to use it as a directory watcher and for new files it works fine. But if a file is deleted camel send no event so my application can be triggered to start the related action for deleted files like unregistering at a database or something else.

Therefore my question: is this possible to implement with apache camel or is it recommended to use the FileWatcher from the jdk?

Comment: I don't think Camel supports that, you might need to look at something like https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is possible at the moment but it looks interesting so it would be nice if you open a [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira) so we won't forget.